# Can't remove element from dictionary

Tags: javascript, dictionary, polymer

Following my previous question : [How get the value of this polymer element ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34754236/how-get-the-value-of-this-polymer-element), I need to remove an element from a dictionary that I pass as an attribute when I import this custom element in another custom element.

**flow-element**

```
<script>
Polymer({
  is: 'flow-element',
  properties: {
    dict: {
      type: String,
      notify: true
    },
    name: {
      type: String
    },
    kind: {
      type: String
    }
  },

  handleClick: function() {
    console.log('clicked: ' + this.name);
    // the output does work
    console.log('Dict before ::' + JSON.stringify(this.dict, null, 4));

    // this does NOT work
    delete this.dict[this.name];

    // the output does work, but dictionary is unchanged
    console.log('Dict after ::' + JSON.stringify(this.dict, null, 4));

  }
});
</script>
```

**flow-list**

```
<flow-element dict={{flowDictionnary}} name="{{item.first}}" kind="{{item.last}}"></flow-element>
```

I am able to access the dictionary (print its content) but for some reason, I can't remove any item from it.

**Research**

This does work : `delete this.dict[0];` (well the element is replace with `null`)

Before

```
{
    "first": "Bob",
    "last": "Smith"
}
{
    "first": "Sally",
    "last": "Johnson"
}
```

After

```
null,
{
    "first": "Sally",
    "last": "Johnson"
}
```

However, the list that displayed the dictionary element does not update, and element stay on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've tried to use `this.splice(path, start, deleteCount)`?
You have to use it as follows:
`this.splice("dict", index, 1)` where `index` refers to the position of the element to remove.
More information about push, pop, splice and other polymer's useful functions [here](http://polymer.github.io/polymer/).

Comment: Thanks a lot! ...And I have another problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34772535/polymer-not-removing-deleted-element