# Polymer not removing deleted element

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer, polymer-1.0

Using the Polymer Stater Kit, I created two custom elements :

- *flow-list.html* (here is declared the **flowElementArray**)
- *flow-element.html* (here is defined the delete function)

In the *app.js* file, I also defined a addElement function.

I can add elements to the *flowElementArray*, and they are displayed.

BUT, when I remove elements from the  *flowElementArray*, they are still displayed.

Here is how I got the following result :

1. App start (2 items pre-loaded)
2. I delete one item (the item stays on the screen)
3. I add one item (the item is added, above the deleted one by the way)

[image]

What could be the source of this weird behaviour ?

**Edit** I couldn't make the example run on plunker/codepen.io/jsbin so here it is on github.

- GitHub repo : https://github.com/JeanReneRobin/octo
- GitHub page : http://jeanrenerobin.github.io/octo/

How I add an element :

```
app.storageLoaded = function() {

  if (this.$.s1.value === '' || this.$.s2.value === '') {
    window.alert('One field is Empty!');
    return;
  }

  this.$.flowListID.push('flowDictionnary',
  {
    first: this.$.s1.value,
    last: this.$.s2.value
  });
};
```

How I remove :

```
removeItem: function() {
  var counter = 0;
  while (counter < this.dict.length) {
    var item = this.dict[counter];
    if (item.first === this.name) {
      this.dict.splice(counter, 1);
    } else {
      counter++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Show us the code so that we can help you. If you do it in jsbin it would be perfect.

Comment: I did not succeed in making a simple custom element from Polymer working on this kind of website (jsbin, codepen, plunker), therefore I decided to upload my work to GitHub and create a GitHub. I know it's not as good as these websites. At least it (not) works exactly as on my computer.

Comment: No one is interested in investigating a whole project. Please provide a minimal example that allows to reproduce the problem (See also http://sscce.org/)

Comment: You'll need to read this: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#array-mutation. Sounds like you didn't use `this.push()` or `this.splice()` to add/remove items from your array.

Comment: I added how I add and remove an element. And I am working on a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing operations on array properties in Polymer, you need to use the `this.push('myArrayProperty', item)`, `this.splice('myArrayProperty', 0, 1)` or call `this.notifyPath('myArrayProperty')` after the operation.

```
removeItem: function() {
  var counter = 0;
  while (counter < this.dict.length) {
    var item = this.dict[counter];
    if (item.first === this.name) {
      // this.dict.splice(counter, 1);
      this.splice('dict', counter, 1);
    } else {
      counter++;
    }
  }
}
```